# Turn arrays into one foreach loop?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have limited PHP knowledge, and I currently have this:

```
$Name= simple_fields_values('Name');
$Description= simple_fields_values('Description');
$Price= simple_fields_values('Price'); 

foreach ($Name as $key_name => $key_value) {
print  $key_value ;
}
foreach ($Description as $key_name => $key_value) {
print $key_value ;
}
foreach ($Price as $key_name => $key_value) {
print $key_value;
}
```

And i Just wanted to know if i can combine this into 1 foreach loop...im sure there is a way, i just dont have the knowledge!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all these three arrays using `array_merge` and then you can use the merged array in a single `foreach` loop.

For eg.,

```
$Name= simple_fields_values('Name');
$Description= simple_fields_values('Description');
$Price= simple_fields_values('Price');

$merge = array_merge($Name,$Description,$Price);

foreach ($merge as $key_name => $key_value) {
print $key_value ;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you ever so much! I've been looking at using array_merge but then I got an invalid argument... Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you find this helpfull, can you please accept and/or vote up the answer :)